# Is there a way to fully test “publish_actions” to comment (other user posts) without submitting app for review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, publish-actions

I created an app on the FB developer page, and correctly configured it to allow “publish_actions”. Also tested to comment my own posts using the graph API and everything went OK.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/xxx/comment
Sending the field message “some comment” (as post)

The problem is whenever that “Comment ID”  does not belong to me, for example a friend or a page post that I am trying to comment, I always get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

(The token generation, and permission requests worked flawlessly, also even added all the permission available to test, but no luck)

Is there any way to test the comment function on other person post or page without submitting the app? Or is there a way to create “test” pages (as there is for test users) to test this?